# kapt not enabling incremental annotation processing

Tags: kotlin, gradle, annotation-processing, kapt

For some reason, Kapt complains that incremental compile is not enabled on one of my modules. However, I see no reason why is shouldn't be.

The warning message when running core:kaptKotlin

```
[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: io.github.mdsimmo.cmdmsg.TextPreprocessor (NON_INCREMENTAL).
```

The error shows that `io.github.mdsimmo.cmdmsg.TextPreprocessor` is the module at fault, but I don't understand why it is not incremental?

I've added `kapt.incremental.apt=true` in every modules' `gradle.properties` (although I shouldn't have to since newer kapt version do that by default).

This is CmdMsgProcessor/build.gradle (the module that contains TextPreProcessor):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.3.72"
    id 'idea'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.+"

    implementation project(":cmdMsg")
    implementation('com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6')
    kapt('com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6')
}
```

And the cmdMsg/build.gradle (the dependency listed in `CmdMsgProcessor/build.gradle`)

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.72"
    id 'idea'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.+"
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official guide for kapt](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html),

> Currently, annotation processing can be incremental only if all annotation 
>   processors being used are incremental.

kapt warns you that `io.github.mdsimmo.cmdmsg.TextPreprocessor` does not support incremental annotation processing, therefore incremental processing is disabled for the entire build.

Comment: I know. The question is "why is TextPreprocessor not incremental"? (I've edited the question to make that more clear)

Comment: There's work that needs to be done to make an annotation processor compatible with incremental processing, here's a good reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:incremental_annotation_processing